# Why can't my .php extension files work in as CGI in cgi-bin folder(linux server)?

Tags: php, linux, hosting, cgi

I recently purchased domain name and hosting from **"www.domain.com"**. My hosting is "Linux Hosting". I prepared a web site with PHP. While I was looking hosting features, there was **PHP5** support. After that, in web site configuration, I noticed that PHP5 support is only avaible as a **cgi application**. Up till now, I didn't know what cgi is. I researched a bit. I noticed that there is a directory called cgi-bin. I put my php files in it but gave internal server error.
But in cgi-bin directory, .cgi extensions work. when I looked from Internet, I understood that there must add some handler into .htaccess or into httpd.conf. I am not authoritized to access these files but I can add some handler from "web site configuration" in my hosting.

Iknow I am doing something wrong but I don't know what it is. Thanks...

Comment: If you have access to the server's logs, check the error log. it'll explain what caused the 500 error.

Comment: Contacting your hosting company's support team would be your best bet, but I'm going to guess that you don't have to put your files in the cgi-bin directory. That directory is a holdover from rather outdated forms of server configuration. Your PHP files should be executable from the normal directory your web files should be stored in (most likely named something like "public_html").

Comment: Hi Albright, as you said there is no need to put php files in cgi-bin folder. In httpdocs directory, all files work but only php4 files. There is no php5 support. For example, my class files aren't work from that directory because classes are available after php5.

Comment: He question was asking "why he can't put php files in cgi-bin".

Answer (score 1):

CGI means that PHP is configured to run as a separate process from your web server (apache usually), as opposed to the module of the web server.

You should be able to simply place the php file at your web root (usually in /var/www), navigate to the file in your browser, and it should all work.

Also, make sure you check your apache logs, in /var/log/

Comment: Yes it works but only php4  files. Not php5 files...  In my error_log, there are following errors : failed to open log file
fopen: Permission denied
Premature end of script headers: test.php

Comment: can you verify the version of your php and let me know?  http://php.net/phpversion

Comment: in httpdocs folders, my php version is PHP 4.4.9 ... But when i try to access my classes(class works as of php5), it doesn't work. My server's PHP5 support is as cgi application. How can I make my files work as cgi?

Comment: Have a look in the control panel for your hosting. Sometimes they provide a simple way to choose which PHP version you want your hosting to have. I have seen this before. And you don't need to alter your code. CGI/module mode of php is only up to server configuration, not specific way of writing code.

Answer (score 0):

Search the hosting documation. I bet you will need to add `#!/path/to/php` at the first line of your scripts.